Why is the "Very Low Quality" flag available for questions?
I recently got some Flags on Questions declined that I have personaly evaluated as very poor.
The Flags got rejected with the following Justification:
"Declined - Questions should NEVER be flagged as very-low-quality"
I sort of understand the reasoning behind this, to not discourage people from asking questions and give more constructive feedback, but why give this Option of a Flag for Questions in the first place then? Shouldn't it be removed if it's not desired?
I Found some question via comments that we're flagged as duplicate to this question only stating the Following:
"The sad truth is, nobody has the foggiest idea what "very low quality" (VLQ) flags on questions are for. This, of course, means that I can't give you an actual answer to your question or even any clear guidance on what to do.
Flaggers don't know or agree on what the VLQ flag means, and neither do moderators."
Another Answer states:
"Almost always, because going on the dictionary definition of "very low quality", pretty much every question that should be closed is of very low quality."
So the Flag should in some opinion apply to all questions that should be closed, on the other hand I am discouraged to use it on any questions.
This is obviously contradicting and should lead to discussion and removing this flag from questions.
It only leads to confusion for the people using it, as well as it leads to additional workload for the mods that have to deal with the flags raised.
I understand that the mods don't design the UI, I simply feel it could be adapted to fit the needs of Users and Mods.

@AbdulAzizBarkat this explains what other flags are a better fit in which situations, but not why you never use VLQ on Questions as well why its available if mods don't want you to use it.

Moderators didn't create the UI.

@Mr.Irrelevant the most upvoted answer there is by a moderator, quoting from their first paragraph: nobody has the foggiest idea what "very low quality" (VLQ) flags on questions are for

if no one knows, why are they available in the context of a question then?

There's a feature request to have it removed. Doesn't seem to have caught the attention of staff or gained much traction though.

lol 10 years ago

Obviously a very low quality question is one which should be deleted (and isn't spam). Closing questions do get them deleted eventually (unless answered and upvoted) but surely there are cases where a question can't be salvaged and there's no harm in deleting it from the start. If the flag achieves that or not, nobody seems to know.

"to not discourage people from asking questions and give more constructive feedback" not really thats not the reasoning behind that. It's just VLQ essentially means "This needs to be deleted" but the reason why it needs to be deleted is left ambiguous. Adding to this we have a set of more suitable flagging / closure reasons that basically cover everything you might cast a VLQ flag for. In essence VLQ flag is wasting moderator time. The answers on the linked question explain all of this very well along with what the flag was intended for and that the moderators want to get rid of it.

oh yeah I forgot, not discouraging people wouldn't be very stack overflowish ;)

anyway I got a lot of duplicate suggestions but none of them explain why this flag can be used on questions in the first place.

tbh I feel like its currently just a trap for your flags to be declined and loosing your privilege to flag stuff

There does seem to be some "do you read Meta?" checks baked into the review process.

I dont feel like meta has a clear answer to my question, the opinion on VLQ on Questions is ambiguous.

RE: So the Flag should in some opinion apply to all questions that should be closed — Cody's opinion, which is largely shared by the moderation team, is quite unambiguous on this: "Moderators aren't really supposed to be your personal question-closing valets"

I understand but still I'm asking myself why this flag is an option then if even mods are annoyed by it.

@Mr.Irrelevant uhh, because the moderators aren't the developers / engineers of the site, neither are they the people who set the priorities of these developers. The moderators are elected by the community from normal users and aren't even Stack Overflow employees.

Moderators sometimes moderate based on their personal opinion. I personally disagree with the assertion that VLQ flags on questions should NEVER be used. Theoretically, they should be used on questions that are basically gibberish but are not deliberately made as an attempt to abuse the system, and thus are not R/A. I.e., questions that you can tell at a glance need to be closed/deleted, without even needing to read them.

@CPlus close vote as unclear -> downvote + del-vote (if possible). I'm with Cody here that this doesn't need moderator attention, it's entirely within the bounds of users handling the content.

I Feel the UI should be designed in a fashion that supports users and mods and doesn't lead to unnecessary flags

@Mr.Irrelevant you have to convince SE about this, not us - the users. This topic, and others, have been brought up again and again. We, the regular users as well as mods, have proven to be insufficient in making SE prioritise aiding the UX particularly when it comes to curation and proper site usage. Improvements to existing UX are hardly ever a priority. Even if SE break something that used to work.
